# Confidential Client requests are not supported on public endpoint for tenants with replication scope USG

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault

I have a Java application that retrieves secret from a Key Vault on the Azure US Sovereign cloud (`https://*****.vault.usgovcloudapi.net`) through an `App Registration` client.

The application has been working fine since I started using the Java SDK. However, while running the application today, retrieving the secret failed. The following exception was thrown:

```
2020-05-08 00:42:32.711 ERROR 2100 --- [onPool-worker-3] c.m.a.m.ConfidentialClientApplication    : [Correlation ID: 6ae589cd-0ebd-4b51-97ad-aa45dc240708] Execution of class com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationGrantSupplier failed.

com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.MsalServiceException: AADSTS900439: Confidential Client requests are not supported on public endpoint for tenants with replication scope USG. Send your requests to https://login.microsoftonline.us
Trace ID: d7bcf956-f161-4e5c-867e-84f79005ac00
Correlation ID: 6ae589cd-0ebd-4b51-97ad-aa45dc240708
Timestamp: 2020-05-07 19:12:42Z
    at com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.MsalServiceExceptionFactory.fromHttpResponse(MsalServiceExceptionFactory.java:46) ~[msal4j-0.5.0-preview.jar:0.5.0-preview]
    at com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.TokenRequest.executeOauthRequestAndProcessResponse(TokenRequest.java:109) ~[msal4j-0.5.0-preview.jar:0.5.0-preview]
    at com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.ClientApplicationBase.acquireTokenCommon(ClientApplicationBase.java:163) ~[msal4j-0.5.0-preview.jar:0.5.0-preview]
    at com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationGrantSupplier.execute(AcquireTokenByAuthorizationGrantSupplier.java:52) ~[msal4j-0.5.0-preview.jar:0.5.0-preview]
    at com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.AuthenticationResultSupplier.get(AuthenticationResultSupplier.java:57) ~[msal4j-0.5.0-preview.jar:0.5.0-preview]
    at com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.AuthenticationResultSupplier.get(AuthenticationResultSupplier.java:17) ~[msal4j-0.5.0-preview.jar:0.5.0-preview]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1700) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.exec(CompletableFuture.java:1692) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:290) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.topLevelExec(ForkJoinPool.java:1020) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:1656) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1594) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:177) ~[na:na]
```

*Some additional details*:
- Operating System - Windows 10
- IDE - Eclipse 2020-03 (4.15.0)
- Azure Key Vault library version - `com.azure:azure-security-keyvault-secrets:4.1.0`

Could someone wxplain why this issue is encountered? I could not find Azure documentation regarding the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When creating your `ConfidentialClientApplication`, use the Government endpoint instead of the public one:

```
        ConfidentialClientApplication app = ConfidentialClientApplication.builder(
                CONFIDENTIAL_CLIENT_ID,
                ClientCredentialFactory.createFromSecret(CONFIDENTIAL_CLIENT_SECRET))
                .authority("https://login.microsoftonline.us/your-tenant-id")
                .build();
```

This has probably been a breaking change which was not well announced(?), since some others are also picking up this all of a sudden, e.g. https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1018249/azure-file-copy-task-login-error-error.html

Comment: I started seeing this error today on our PowerApps Gateway.

Comment: hi @alex! adding an `authority` helped me. thanks! also, since I am using the `azure-identity` library's APIs, I just wanted to mention this- for those who are using `com.azure.identity.ClientSecretCredential` to instantiate a `SecretClient` instance, use the `authorityHost(String)` method to specify the login URL of your sovereign cloud.